# Converting hex numbers into decimal format

Tags: c, csv, hex

This code reads a csv file with numbers in hex format, transforms them into decimal format and writes the decimal numbers into another file.

```
/* Author: Madalina Erascu*/
/* Input:  csv file with numbers in hexa fomat
   Output: csv file with numbers in decimal fomat with 80 decimals
   Usage: main list_input_files list_output_files
   Attention: function hex2double - the specifier llx might not give the same output on computers with other OS than Windows, MinGW compiler, etc.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long double hex2double(const char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char buffer[1024] ;
   char *record,*line;
   long double x;
   int i,j;

   printf( "argc = %d\n", argc );
   for( i = 1; i <= argc/2; ++i ) {
       printf( "argv[ %d ] = %s\n", i, argv[ i ] );
       printf( "argv[ %d ] = %s\n", (argc/2) + i, argv[ (argc/2) + i ] );

       FILE *fstream_in =  fopen(argv[  i           ],"r");
       FILE *fstream_out = fopen(argv[ (argc/2) + i ],"w");

       if(fstream_in == NULL) {
            printf("\nFile opening failed:", fstream_in);
            return -1 ;
       }

       int idx = 0;

       while((line=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fstream_in))!=NULL) {
            record = strtok(line,",");
            while(record != NULL) {
                    idx++;
                    printf("String : %d|%s|\n",idx,record) ;
                    x = hex2double(record) ;
                    fprintf(fstream_out,"%.80e\n", x);
                    record = strtok(NULL,",");
            }
       }
    }
    return 0 ;
    }

long double hex2double(const char *s)
{
    long double d = 0.0;
    sscanf(s, "%llx",  &d);

    return d;
}
```

When I use the file at this link as input:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64621064/trigon_batch2.csv.

the 61th number in the file is split into 2 numbers. The numers in hexa format are actually floating point numbers, not integers...

Any explanation?

Comment: `llx` of sscanf for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: This `printf("\nFile opening failed:", fstream_in);` is undefined behavior! Why did you pass the stream as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `sscanf()` for that, use `strtoll()` instead like this

   ```
   return (double) strtoll(s, NULL, 16);
   ```

   If you want to check for errors, pass a non `NULL` pointer as the `endptr` and check for the not converted characters, you can also check with `sscanf()`, but it's simply not suitable for this situation.

   Also, I would not write such code. I am just helping you fix your problem and I think this will do it. Although, it doesn't make sense to convert an integer to double if you are reading it without any decimal values then it doesn't make sense to convert to double.
2. Another problem that you have is this

   ```
   printf("\nFile opening failed:", fstream_in);
   ```

   It is wrong for multiple reasons:

   - The NEW LINE character is used for controlling the buffering of the stdio output functions, they are said to be *line buffered* and thus, the `'\n'` character "*flushes*" the buffer, so it makes sense that it be placed at the end of a line.
   - It's UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, because you are passing a parameter to `printf()` but there is no specifier for it, if you want a message telling the user that the file did not open, pass the file name like this

     ```
     printf("failure opening %s\n", argv[i]);
     ```
3. You should also check the file you open for writing against `NULL`, the only reason for `fopen()` to fail is not that the file didn't exist. Consider not having permission to write in the target directory, it will also return `NULL` and then your code will invoke UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR.

Comment: return (double) strtoll(s, NULL, 16); does not solve. The other 2 suggestions are orthogonal and don't solve it either... I edited the initial post; actually in the file the 61th number is split into 2 numbers. The numbers in hexa format are actually floating point numbers, not integers... So weird!

Comment: @MadalinaErascu Hello, I have solved the problem! You are right, they are floating point values going from -*pi* to *pi* ... If you would like the code, please write to iharob@gmail.com

Comment: @iharob - Can you please add the code to your answer so others may benefit?